# How to plot all named columns in a pandas multiindexed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I wrote a script to read a series of Excel using pandas.read_excel() into a DataFrame. 
Then these DataFrames are convert to MultiIndexed DataFrames.
Their struture is as follows:

```
         Customer1               Customer2              Customer3
     Var1   Var2   Var3      Var1   Var2   Var3     Var1   Var2   Var3 
0     1       6     4         6      2      5         7      6      6
1     3       5     0         1      5      4         1      6      5
2     5       7     3         6      1      4         7      5      1
.     .       .     .         .      .      .         .      .      .
.     .       .     .         .      .      .         .      .      .
100   1       6     4         6      2      4         7      6      6
```

How can I then plot all the the "Var2" data against the index, in both combined and singulated plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select `MultiIndex` with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
print (df.xs('Var2', axis=1, level=1))
     Customer1  Customer2  Customer3
0            6          2          6
1            5          5          6
2            7          1          5
100          6          2          6

df.xs('Var2', axis=1, level=1).plot()
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the answer! Gotta read up more on the what axis and level meant and whether I can address them by names.